# Total average of complex divided numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Spreasheet:**

```
             A                       B            C           D         E  
1                                  TOTAL       January    February     March
2  Expected Workload                900         200         300         400
3  Workload doable per employee     150          50          50          50 
4  Needed employees (net)            6.0         4.0         6.0        8.0 
5  Sickness                         31%         30%         25%        35%
6  Needed employees (gross)          8.7         5.7         8.0        12.3
```

**Formulas:**

```
B2 = SUM(C2:E2)
B3 = SUM(C3:E3)
B4 = B2/B3
B5 = 1-(B4/B6)
B6 = (C4/(1-C5)+D4/(1-D5)+E4/(1-E5))/COUNTA(C6:E6)

C4 = C2/C3
C6 = C4/(1-C5)

D3 = C3
D4 = D2/D3
D6 = D4/(1-D5)

E3 = D3
E4 = E2/E3
E6 = E4/(1-E5)
```

As you can see in the spreadsheet above I am calculating the needed employees for a certain workload for each month. All this works perfectly so far.

My issue is in **Cell B6**. In this cell I am currently using the following formula to get the average of the month `Jan-Feb`:

```
B6 = (C4/(1-C5)+D4/(1-D5)+E4/(1-E5))/COUNTA(C6:E6)
```

The formula works but as you can see I manually add the result of each month and then divide it by the `COUNTA` function. In my original file I will have 24 or more months so it will be a lot of work to add each month manually to this formula.

Do you know any formula to avoid this manual adding? 
Maybe something similar to the `SUMPRODUCT` function?

Comment: @pnuts That's what I thought too but the last formula i the question refers to 2 different rows... which makes it not an average?

Comment: @pnuts It's taking an average of Sickness% and Gross (#)?

Comment: @ashleedawg: Yes the formula in C6 is correct. For example in January I calculate that I need 4.0 employees to do the workload of 200. However, now I know that 10% of the employees might be sick so I have to add those 10% to the 4.0 employees and therefore finally I need 5.7 employees to also cover the sick rate of 10% and to have 4.0 employees in the end.

Comment: No it says B6 is the issue.

Comment: Typo sorry: I meant:   Double click on cell `B6`. Is it pointing at the cells/areas that you intended?  How is that going return Jan & Feb?  See my answer below.

Comment: Yes, it is all correct. I also doublechecked in my Excel spreadsheet here on my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be one volatile formula that does the job:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT("C4:"&CHAR(64+COUNTA(4:4))&4),1/(1-INDIRECT("C5:"&CHAR(64+COUNTA(5:5))&5)))/COUNTA(INDIRECT("C6:"&CHAR(64+COUNTA(6:6))&6))
```

Or this one that will work beyond column `Z`:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("C6:"&ADDRESS(6,COUNTA(5:5))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your spreadsheet is very confusing but you say that in `Cell B6` you want:

> the average of the month Jan-Feb

I can only assume that you want the average "`Needed Employees`" for January 7 February (but not March for some reason?).

So you would enter this formula in B4:

```
=AVERAGE(C6:D6)
```

You definitely should not be adding any numbers manually for Excel, and any time that you are, you should instead be Googling to learn how to use Excel.  There are plenty of tutorials out there to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

use this as an array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(C4:INDEX(4:4,MATCH(1E+99,4:4))/(1-C5:INDEX(5:5,MATCH(1E+99,4:4))))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter insted of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

This is a non volatile formula, as in it will only recalc if the data in row 4 or 5 changes.  Volatile formulas recalc every time anything changes on any sheet or workbook open:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean unnecessary?  The op wanted the range to automatically increase based on the data. So as more data is inserted the formula would expand to include new data without the need of resizing the range manually.

Comment: But that is not what was asked. You are assuming those are there and not just showing the parts. The op asked how to do it in one formula. And since it is an array formula it should only include the actual data and not any extra.

Comment: So because your assumption is different than mine it deserves a down vote?

Comment: And to me, getting rid of the helper cells and doing a single formula is easier. As to what the op wants my guess is they wanted the single formula by the fact that they selected the single formula solution over the "simple". And is why I posted mine as an alternative to a volatile formula.